# how do i rerun a function and update variable values?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

This code below works correctly, however it only runs the first time because the variables are not getting updated on the completion of the function. I can tell from the return of `console.log($(xyz))` only the initial value, `#100` is returned.

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  var xyz = $('.nextinst').last().attr('href')
  var mod = $('.modal'+xzy)
  var turn = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')    
  var craw = $('.glyphicon-chevron-right').last()
  $(craw).on('click', function() {

    if (!$(mod).size() > 0) {
    $.getScript(turn); 
    }
    setTimeout (function() {
      $(xyz).modal()
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

I have searched several topics about setTimeout and SetInterval but I have not gotten anything to work correctly.

**Edit:**

I have an instagram like web app where a thumbnail is displayed on the main page and a modal displays the full image. the modals can be clicked through with previous and next. it is a rails project, the photos are paginated 9 at a time. that means that when in the modal, if you click previous, but the previous photo has no yet been loaded into the DOM, it will not load.

`var xyz = $('.nextinst').last().attr('href')` returns the `href` which is the `id` of the photo that the last previous button in the DOM is linking towards. So if photos #1-9 are already paginated, `xyz = #10`

`var mod = $('.modal'+xzy)` this is going to be used in the `if statement` in the function to check if the `modal` for that picture has been loaded in the DOM yet.

`var turn = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')` this is the href link to the next page of photos.

`var craw = $('.glyphicon-chevron-right').last()` is the last previous button.

so what happens is that when the last previous button is clicked, it checks if the object/photo exists in the DOM, if it does not, then the next page of photos are paginated. then the modal for that photo is opened in the `setTimout` function.

This all works correctly, however after all of this is done, I need it to all start again and for `xyz` to be given a new value. From the above example. We start with photos #1-9, `xyz` = `#10`. Then we add 9 more photos, so we now have photos #1-18 loaded in the DOM. Now when the function restarts `xyz` should equal `#19`.

Comment: References to 4 class selectors without HTML without any example of what result is expected, or even what purpose the function does. Please rectify this by providing a [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne please let me know if this explanation makes it clearer. I cannot create a jfiddle because the problem relies on photos being paginated from the database.

Comment: So you need to know where you came from in order to get where you are going. Keep in mind my answer may be simplistic and not easily integrated into your app having no way of testing the app or a working semi-facsimile thereof.

Comment: I don't think you need help with the jQuery, it's the Rails that's most likely your culprit, see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18770517/2813224)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With turbolinks 5 you use the following wrapper:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){

});
```